# margin auto не работает

Tags: html, css

Почему блок "MAKESHOP.PRO И CS-CART" на странице [makeshop.pro/24500](https://makeshop.pro/24500) не выравнивает его посередине?

У блока задана ширина, 1200px.

Comment: Напишите ваш код прямо сюда.

Comment: Переходите на Bootstrap 3 и 4, новые сайты на старом фреймворке делать не стоит. Что у вас не работает, так и непонятно, приведите пример неработающего кода прямо сюда.

Comment: у меня блок с заданной шириной не перемещается по-середине, хотя для него задан margin:auto
Сейчас, для блока "MAKESHOP.PRO И CS-CART" задан     margin-left: 10%;, что неправильно

Могу конечно предоставить весь css и html, но там будет много лишнего. Проще наверное, смотреть на живом примере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот у этого класса `span16 block-white partners max-width-1200` должны быть такие стили:

```
margin: 0 auto;
float: none;
```

Сам float и "отменяет" выравнивание блочного элемента по центру.

Comment: Гениально! спасибо) а то, уже не знал, что делать)

Comment: Вот поэтому советую сделать свою "сетку" стилей, чтобы знать откуда ноги растут. удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно обернуть ваш блок в div c подобным стилем

```
div_style{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:1200px;
}
```

Comment: Да, так можно сделать, лучше даже добавить к блоку с .row-fluid (он генерируется автоматически. что-то туда добавить, проблематично)
Но как можно это починить для текущей структуры? почему оно не работает сейчас?